# how to export and load mysql database in vscode sqltools extension

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, sqltools

I'm using Apache2.4 as my server, php8.1, and sqltools extension in vscode. I wonder how can I export and import/load mysql database from and to another device and set it up on sqltools, so that I can connect it to my php code
Should I also export/import the connection so that I'm able to use the mysql database?

I received a .json and .session.sql file, are those 2 files enough for me to load the database in my sqltools now?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Dumping a database is done best with something like `mysqldump`

Comment: @NicoHaase My friend and I are both beginners, and I'm continuing her work. She sent me .json file and .session.sql file (we both don't know whether those 2 files are enough for me to load it in my device). I'm still figuring a way to load the database into my sqltools. I haven't read about mysqldump, I will try looking for it.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: "are those 2 files enough for me to load the database" - why not try it out and see what happens? Usually, a database dump contains of a single SQL file